# Why is JPATH_ROOT set to "[ROOT]"?

Tags: untagged

Is this a Joomla 4 change? It used to be set to a proper folder before. We have `require_once` calls that fail because of this. Worked in Joomla 3, not sure what changed during bootstrap here.

Only place I can find in the code is libraries/src/Filesystem/Path.php:removeRoot where they replace root with the string "[ROOT]".

Maybe using JPATH_SITE would work instead...

Maybe not a problem, just the LogEntry cleaning the message from root folder path.

Comment: You probably misunderstood something on this. `JPATH_ROOT` is only set to (removed) `”[ROOT]”` in messages, otherwise it is defined in defines.php and in app.php in includes folder at bootstrapping Joomla: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/tree/4.2-dev/includes . Probably something else is causing problems on require.

Comment: @Zollie Yes, thank you, I realized the string was filtered via the LogEntry class. :) So a new feature in Joomla 4.